# barra de busqueda en html y javascript

Tags: html5

Hola buenas a tardes a esta comunidad estoy tratando de hacer una barra de busqueda en html y boopstrap y ya lo consegui,
[image: codigo de barra de busqueda]

pero ahora quiero que indexe en mi pagina web, hice un busqueda.html y ahi meti toda la informacion que quiero que sea indexada lo hice con un  datatables(https://datatables.net/) y si me indexa y busca lo que yo pido

[image: filtrado con datables]

Ahora lo que quiero es que cuando le de click en mi barra de busqueda "cualquier palabra" me busque en el  busqueda.html y muestre los resultados o coincidencias.

Ojala alguien me pueda ayudar ya me trabe, de antemano se los agradezco, gracias.

Comment: Añade el codigo en forma te codigo, no como imagen e incluye tambien el codigo javascript

Comment: <!--- este es la barra de busqueda -->    <div class="w3_search">
    <form action="busqueda.html" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Busqueda" required="">
     <input type="submit" value="Ir">
    </form>
   </div>

Comment: <!--  Funcion inicializacion datatablemin   -->
 <script> $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tablemovies').DataTable();
} ); </script>